# Can I travel within US if I have an H3 Visa?

Tags: visas, usa

I have an H3 visa (Trainee visa) which allows me to enter the US for a specific amount of time.I am not a US citizen nor do I possess any state ID's, I will be in training in our Head Quarters in California.

My question is, am I allowed to fly domestically to other states with my foreign passport and a valid H3 visa?

Comment: Absolutely: once you enter the US, you can fly domestically with only your passport, and you shouldn't be asked for your visa (although, lately, who knows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you are legally inside the United States you are allowed to travel freely anywhere within the country (with the possible exception of those on some transit visas).

You will need to produce ID to get on a plane, but your passport should be sufficient.

Comment: This is true except for holders of C (transit) visas.

Comment: @phoog Are you sure? A C3 has a very limited stay, but if they had time to take another flight and back couldn't they do it?

Comment: Well I was confused. I originally intended to note just the C-2, which certainly restricts domestic travel.

Comment: Even with  a C2, if you had a 24 hour layover could you not use those 24 hours to fly somewhere for a visit?

Comment: @phoog: C-2 says you may only travel to and from the UN.  But in principle you could use a domestic flight to get there.  Imagine a diplomat traveling from Australia SYD-LAX-JFK.  They'd have to board a domestic flight for LAX-JFK.  It seems to me C-2 would allow that.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes you can fly from LA to NY on a C-2 visa, but that's not the same as traveling freely around the country.  And, DJClayworth, no you can't take a detour during your trip to NY. The visa authorizes only immediate and direct travel to and from the area within 25 miles of Columbus Circle. See https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-11261/0-0-0-17197/0-0-0-17509.html#0-0-0-12693.